# Synchronised clocks to Start Event

Tags: java, time, synchronization, timespan

I have been researching about how to synchronize clock System. I'm not sure if I get it right. in order to expose my problem in an easy way, I write some code. let say that I would like to print in a console "Something" synchronized with several computers that are connected with my computer via socket server. My idea is this:

the code in my computer:

```
public static void SendMessage()throws Exception{
    String TIME_SERVER = "time-a.nist.gov";
    boolean state = true;
    NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
    TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
    timeInfo.computeDetails();
    long timeSpan = System.currentTimeMillis()+10000;//more 10s
    Date dateSpan = new Date(systemtime + timeInfo.getOffset());
    //then I send the dateSpan.getTime() via oscMessage for all computer
   while(state){
       long systemTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       Date realdate = new Date(systemtime + timeInfo.getOffset());
       if(dateSpan.getTime()==realdate.getTime()) {
           System.out.println("Something");
           state = false;
       }
   }
}
```

//In the computer Clients the code is more or less this:

```
public receiveMessage(long dateSpan)throws Exception{
    String TIME_SERVER = "time-a.nist.gov";
    boolean state = true;
    NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
    TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
    timeInfo.computeDetails();
    while(state){
        long systemtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Date realdate = new Date(systemtime + timeInfo.getOffset());
        if(dateSpan.getTime()==realdate.getTime()) {
            System.out.println("Something");
            state = false;
        }

    }
}
```

I omit some parts of the code related to how I send the oscMessage I am basically using the oscP5 library. My question is:
The Way I implements this code, ensure that all computer are going to print "Something at the same time independent from their system clock?
Any better suggestions?!
Thank in advance

Comment: The use of `==` may be risky. Can you guarantee that it will be checked every millisecond? Aside from that avoid the old `Date` class. It has been replaced with `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Yes you are write the while loop doesn't guarantee a granularity of 1ms. I will put >=. Ok I will follow your suggest about Instant instead of date. Thank your for you reply. I thought this was a dead post already